# Silverstripe Elemental Module Composer install error

Tags: php, silverstripe-4

I have a clean install of Silverstripe running 4.

I am trying to install this module: https://github.com/dnadesign/silverstripe-elemental/tree/2.1

Command:

> composer require dnadesign/silverstripe-elemental 2.x-dev

and I get this error in composer:

```
    Loading composer repositories with package information
Updating dependencies                                                     
Your requirements could not be resolved to an installable set of packages.

Problem 1
- Conclusion: don't install dnadesign/silverstripe-elemental 2.1.2
- Conclusion: don't install dnadesign/silverstripe-elemental 2.1.1
- Conclusion: don't install dnadesign/silverstripe-elemental 2.1.0
- Conclusion: don't install dnadesign/silverstripe-elemental 2.0.1
- Conclusion: don't install dnadesign/silverstripe-elemental 2.0.0
- Conclusion: don't install dnadesign/silverstripe-elemental 2.0.0-beta1
- Installation request for dnadesign/silverstripe-elemental-list dev-master -> satisfiable by dnadesign/silverstripe-elemental-list[dev-master].
- don't install dnadesign/silverstripe-elemental 2.2.x-dev|install dnadesign/silverstripe-elemental 2.x-dev
- Conclusion: don't install dnadesign/silverstripe-elemental 2.x-dev
- Conclusion: don't install dnadesign/silverstripe-elemental 2.1.x-dev
- dnadesign/silverstripe-elemental-list dev-master requires dnadesign/silverstripe-elemental >=3.0 -> satisfiable by dnadesign/silverstripe-elemental[3.0.x-dev, 3.1.x-dev, 3.x-dev, 3.2.x-dev, 4.0.x-dev, dev-master, 4.x-dev].
- Can only install one of: dnadesign/silverstripe-elemental[3.0.x-dev, 2.0.x-dev].
- Can only install one of: dnadesign/silverstripe-elemental[3.1.x-dev, 2.0.x-dev].
- Can only install one of: dnadesign/silverstripe-elemental[3.x-dev, 2.0.x-dev].
- Can only install one of: dnadesign/silverstripe-elemental[3.2.x-dev, 2.0.x-dev].
- Can only install one of: dnadesign/silverstripe-elemental[4.0.x-dev, 2.0.x-dev].
- Can only install one of: dnadesign/silverstripe-elemental[dev-master, 2.0.x-dev].
- Can only install one of: dnadesign/silverstripe-elemental[4.x-dev, 2.0.x-dev].
- Installation request for dnadesign/silverstripe-elemental 2.* -> satisfiable by dnadesign/silverstripe-elemental[2.0.0, 2.0.0-beta1, 2.0.1, 2.0.x-dev, 2.1.0, 2.1.1, 2.1.2, 2.1.x-dev, 2.x-dev, 2.2.x-dev].
```

Answer (score 1):

Why don't you try installing `composer require dnadesign/silverstripe-elemental dev-master` rather than `2.x-dev` since you have a clean install of ss4.

https://addons.silverstripe.org/add-ons/dnadesign/silverstripe-elemental

Comment: `^4` would be better, it's the latest stable release line

Comment: Don't require `dev-master` if you don't need to... Always look for the latest stable release. If you _really_ need the latest bugfix, take the feature branch, as dev-master might one day be incompatible with your current installation. This could be like `4.x-dev as 4.0.3` when 4.0.2 is the current release.